# $R$-Scheme $X$ and $X$'s generic fiber has the same dimension as $S$-scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $R$ be an integral domain.
Suppose that $X$⊂ $\Bbb P_R^3$ is givens by a single homogeneous equation $f(x,y,z)＝0$ with coefficients in $R$. Then, the generic fiber of $X$ is the variety defined by the same equation $f(x,y,z)＝0$.

In this case, $X$ and $X$'s generic fiber are the same dimension.

But does this hold in general ?

That is,
$R$-Scheme $X$ and $X$'s generic fiber has the same dimension as $S$-scheme?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not true as stated (not even in your example). Take $R=\Bbb Z$ and $f=x$ : then you get a copy of the projective line over the integers, which is two dimensional, while the generic fiber is the projective line over the rationals, which is one-dimensional. (I'm assuming you're really in the projective plane from how you've written your equations.) Let me also add that this question is missing context and motivation like many of those you've asked recently. It would really help to add that!

Comment: Thank you for your example ! I'm thinking Neron model (2-dimensional scheme), which is generic fiber of elliptic curve over field.(dimension of $X$)＞(dimension of generic fiber of $X$)$ holds  in general?

Comment: The generic fiber is homeomorphic to a subset of $X$, hence its dimension does not exceed that of $X$.